# Bad request returning when Id is present and correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue with a piece of code. The process should be that when a valid Id is passed through, the code should skip past my 'bad request' if statement and onto showing my view. However, this is not happening and it is falling into bad request.

```
public ActionResult UserDetails(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        return View(userDetailView);
    }
```

This is only a snippet, as the if statement is at the top of this ActionResult and it never gets past it. I know the id is correct, as the webpage shows it correctly in the URL as:

```
TestWebApplication/Users/UserDetails/32
```

and i've even tried changing it to:

```
TestWebApplication/Users/UserDetails?id=32
```

just to try and see if it would work if typed manually. However, no luck.

Has anyone got any ideas as to what could be the issue here? I'm totally lost!

Comment: Have you got correct routing for that Url with the id parameter?

Comment: Yes, in my RouteConfig.cs it is set to the default: url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }. And other pages are working correctly which is why I can't figure out what is different with this specific page.

Comment: Have you tried placing a break point or a logging code in the line `if (id == null)` ?

Comment: Hello... If you've a null-able param, I think you need to check if id.HasValue

Comment: If you comment out the null check completely, so it just returns the view, does it work?

Comment: Are there any MVC Attributes on the UserController or the given Action?

Comment: As @ehsan88 said , you put break point and check your breakpoint gets hit or not  if it is hitting then you can figure out the problem otherwise problem might be with the route.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have just ran through it using breakpoints and commenting/ uncommenting sections of code in the controller. I have found that the id is correct and is returning, but there is an issue when it tries to return the view. Will thins issue lie within the markup of the view trying to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER FOUND:**
I have found the issue with this. The Id is correct and working its way through the code fine. The issue lied within the view for the ActionResult in the controller. I had a line of code which was trying to display the users details on the page using an Id before the Id had been assigned to it from the current page.

Thank you for everyone's help, it is much appreciated!